# How to display data from multiple tables using an Android ListFragment

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have an [Android app](https://github.com/wholcomb/smoke_tracker) that tracks habits and displays a list of recorded events in a [ListFragment](https://github.com/wholcomb/smoke_tracker/blob/master/src/org/dhappy/habits/EventListFragment.java) acting as a Cursor LoaderManager:

```
public class EventListFragment extends ListFragment
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
```

The issue I am facing is I would like to record mood information and display it in the events list. I am correctly recording the data, but I am uncertain how to get data from both the `event` table and the `reading` table.

Currently I use the `onCreateLoader` method to return the data:

```
static final String[] EVENTS_PROJECTION = new String[] {
    EventTable.TABLE_EVENT + "." + EventTable.COLUMN_ID,
    HabitTable.COLUMN_NAME,
    HabitTable.COLUMN_COLOR,
    EventTable.TABLE_EVENT + "." + EventTable.COLUMN_TIME
};

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), HabitContentProvider.EVENTS_URI, EVENTS_PROJECTION, null, null, EventTable.COLUMN_TIME + " DESC");
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    // Populate list
}
```

Which executes the following query:

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
⋮
queryBuilder.setTables(HabitTable.TABLE_HABIT + " JOIN " + EventTable.TABLE_EVENT
                       + " ON " + HabitTable.TABLE_HABIT + "." + HabitTable.COLUMN_ID + " = " + EventTable.TABLE_EVENT + "." + EventTable.COLUMN_HABIT_ID);
⋮
SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, null, sortOrder);
```

This only allows me to create a single Cursor. Is there a simple method for selecting data from multiple tables?

Comment: You could try to create additional URI (TABLE_HABIT_WITH_EVENTS for example) for your joined tables and then use this uri in your Provider.query() implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want to achieve.

If you want to specify multiple endpoints and the way they should be joined on the loader level, I'm not aware of any existing solution.

If you ask about nicer way of doing the sql JOINs than String concatenation in SQliteQueryBuilder's table param, I recently wrote a fluent sqlite interface for [android-db-commons library](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-db-commons), so you can write:

```
select()
    .columns(projection)
    .from(HabitTable.TABLE_HABIT)
    .join(EventTable.TABLE_EVENT)
    .on(column(HabitTable.TABLE_HABIT, HabitTable.COLUMN_ID).eq().column(EventTable.TABLE_EVENT, EventTable.COLUMN_HABIT_ID))
    .where(selection, selectionArgs)
    .orderBy(sortOrder);
```